# Azure BlobNotFound when downloading in SpringBoot app

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-blob-storage

I have a task to make possibility to download simple .txt files from the application using Azure Blob Storage. The code is supposed to work. I didn't write it, but it looks OK to me and from what I'll show later in this post, it really connects to the Azure, and, what's more important, it really works only when I'm testing the app on localhost, but not on the publicly available site.

These are the steps I made:

1. uploaded files to the storage (the underlined is one of them):
   [image]
2. added proper link to the button that should download the attachment via REST API
3. of course, I've also added reference to the attachment in the database (its ID, name etc.)
4. here's how it looks on frontend:
   [image]
5. And this is what I get:
   [image]

I've seen somewhere that it might be caused by Azure CORS settings that don't allow the app to access the storage. Here's what I've done so far:

1. went to portal.azure.com and changed CORS settings like this:
   [image]
2. found something about putting some code into the app under this Microsoft link, but it's not Java. I guess there are some analogical ways in Java: 
   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2014/02/03/windows-azure-storage-introducing-cors/ . Is it necessary after the CORS rules have been added in the Azure Portal?

Also, I've found information that it may be caused by the storage access permissions. The Public Access Level is set to Container:
[image]

Not sure if it gives anything, but these are the container's properties:
[image]

What else can be the problem with the `BlobNotFound` error I receive? Hope I've put enough information here, but if some more is needed say in comment and I'll provide it.

This is the code that's supposed to download the attachment of this method, contained in 3 classes:

Controller class part:

```
@GetMapping("/download/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void downloadAttachment(@PathVariable long id, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
       dataUploadRequestAttachmentService.downloadStaticAttachment(response, id);
    }
```

Controller service class part:

```
public void downloadStaticAttachment(HttpServletResponse response, long id) throws IOException {
        ArticleAttachment articleAttachment = this.findAttachment(id);
        String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(articleAttachment.getName());

        if (mimeType == null){
            mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
        }

        response.setContentType(mimeType);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", articleAttachment.getName()));

        azureBlobStorageArticleAttachmentService.downloadArticleAttachment(
                articleAttachment.getName(),
                articleAttachment.getId(),
                response.getOutputStream()
        );
    }
```

And the AzureBlobStorageArticleAttachmentService class:

```
public void downloadArticleAttachment(String attachmentName, Long articleId, OutputStream outputStream) {
        try {
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(String.format("%s_%s", articleId, attachmentName));
            blob.download(outputStream);
        } catch (URISyntaxException | StorageException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error(String.format("Download article attachment %s error", attachmentName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show some code about how you download the blob?

Comment: of course. I've already edited the post and added the code to the end section of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lee Liu's suggestion about the Blob name was correct when I managed to find out the correct application address. It turned out that domain address visible by user was ending with "azureedge.net", but there's a different one when I went into portal.azure.com. It caused the main problem. After that, I indeed found problem with correct Blob names in storage - because of `String.format`, I had to add their ID in database with a "_" sign, then they started to be downloaded with content instead of empty files.
It seems that the code was OK, it was the problem with improper address and file names.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, please debug to check if you get the correct blob name in the code: `CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(String.format("%s_%s", articleId, attachmentName));`

Here is a demo about how to download blobs using Java SDK for your reference:

```
/// <summary>
/// download blob to memory
/// </summary>
/// <param name="containerName">blob container name</param>
/// <param name="blobName">blob Name</param>
public static ByteArrayOutputStream downloadBlobToMemory(String containerName, String blobName) {
    CloudStorageAccount account = null;
    CloudBlobContainer container = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = null;
    try {
        account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(ConnString);
        CloudBlobClient client = account.createCloudBlobClient();
        container = client.getContainerReference(containerName);
        container.createIfNotExists();
        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = container.getBlockBlobReference(blobName);         

        byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        cloudBlockBlob.download(byteArrayOutputStream);         

    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return byteArrayOutputStream;
}


/// <summary>
/// download blob to local disk
/// </summary>
/// <param name="containerName">blob container name</param>
/// <param name="blobName">blob Name</param>
/// <param name="filePath"> for example: C:\\Test\test.txt</param>
public static void downloadBlobToDisk(String containerName, String blobName, String filePath) {
    CloudStorageAccount account = null;
    CloudBlobContainer container = null;
    try {
        account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(ConnString);
        CloudBlobClient client = account.createCloudBlobClient();
        container = client.getContainerReference(containerName);
        container.createIfNotExists();
        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = container.getBlockBlobReference(blobName);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        cloudBlockBlob.download(fileOutputStream);
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```